# Matrix Exponentiation for 2D array Dynamic Programming

Tags: algorithm, matrix, dynamic-programming

I've just read about a another way solve some Dynamic Programming problems (such as calculating large Fibonacci numbers) using [Matrix Exponentiation](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/matrix-exponentiation/). I wonder if there's any way to use this method to solve Dynamic Programming problems with 2D arrays.

An example of Dynamic Programming problems with 2D arrays:

```
C[i][0] = 0 for all i
C[0][j] = 1 for all j
C[0][0] = 1

C[i][j] = C[i][j-1] + C[i-1][j-1]
```

Calculate C[i][j] for really large i and j (such as 10^9)

Comment: Yes? Under the assumption that `C[i][j-1]` and `C[i-1][j-1]` have already been calculated, which adds an initialization restriction.